# Document object inside self executing function using JSDoc

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

So I have several object definitions that work like this:

```
(function () {
var parent= constructors.Parent.prototype;

/**
 * Creates an instance of Child.
 * 
 * @constructor
 * @augments Parent
 * @this {Child} 
 * @param {object} settings
 */
var Child= function(settings) {
    constructors.Parent.apply(this, arguments); //calling parent constructor
    //constructor code
}

Child.prototype= new constructors.Parent();

/**
 * Method1
 *
 * @this {Child}
 * @param {string} param1
 * @param {number} param2
 */
Child.prototype.method1= function(param1, param2)  {
    parent.method1.apply(this,arguments); //calls "super"
    //method code
}
constructors.Child= Child;
}());
```

I do all this so that only global variable is 'constructors' and so that I don't have to say 'construtors.Child' all the time. But JSDoc3 is ignoring my comments and generates nothing on this code. Anyone knows any special tags to fix this? I don't mind if the JSDoc shows my class name as 'Child' or 'constructors.Child', either way is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it, but it worked:

On another file I now have the following:

```
/**
 * @module constructors
 */
constructors= {}
```

And in the file mentioned before I now have:

```
/**
 * @exports constructors
 */
(function () {
var parent= constructors.Parent.prototype;

/**
 * Creates an instance of Child.
 * 
 * @constructor
 * @augments Parent
 * @this {Child} 
 * @param {object} settings
 */
var Child= function(settings) {
    constructors.Parent.apply(this, arguments); //calling parent constructor
    //constructor code
}

Child.prototype= new constructors.Parent();

/**
 * Method1
 *
 * @this {Child}
 * @param {string} param1
 * @param {number} param2
 */
Child.prototype.method1= function(param1, param2)  {
    parent.method1.apply(this,arguments); //calls "super"
    //method code
}
constructors.Child= Child;
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

use `@public` in front of `@class/@module/@namespace`
see https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/442